# How to define a macro of two tokens in Cpp

Tags: c-preprocessor

In my Arduinoc (cpp) code, I have these macros that set/clear bit y of register x:

```
#define SET(x,y) x |= (1 << y)
#define CLEAR(x,y) x &= ~(1<< y)
```

In several places I then use:

```
CLEAR(PORTB,7)
```

or

```
SET(PORTB,7)
```

I would like to define a macro to be PORTB,7  so it only appear once, in a header file, not all over my code. (I show only one example, but I have several conbinations of PORTx,N in my code).

I tried:

```
#define CLOCK PORTB,7
#define CLOCK_HIGH SET(CLOCK)
```

but it then fails to build with:

```
error: macro "SET" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given  CLOCK_HIGH; delay(DELAY); CLOCK_LOW; delay(DELAY);
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to summarize the question in a oneline tittle. Feel free to reword the title.

Comment: Please post a full [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first expand the macro inside. Ie. do another pass. Your code may look like this:

```
#define SET(x,y)      do{ (x) |=  (1u << (y)); }while(0)
#define CLEAR(x,y)    do{ (x) &= ~(1u << (y)); }while(0)

#define HIGH(a)       SET(a) // another empty pass, just forward
// the `a` is expanded and the second `SET` takes two arguments
// or better, but not fully compliant:
// #define HIGH(...)  SET(__VA_ARGS__)

#define CLOCK         PORTB, 7
#define CLOCK_HIGH()  HIGH(CLOCK)

int main() {
    int PORTB;
    CLOCK_HIGH();
}
```

As a good measure research about [macro pitfalls](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html) and research good [practices when writing macros.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#macros-enums-and-rtl).

Comment: THanks I see that works. I'll have to see to understand it. I find it quite convoluted... I was expecting something easier I guess, but thanks :).

I see you enclosed my macros in do{  }while(0), is it a best practice? Is it not going to slow down the code somehow? I need it to go as fast as possible (that why I'm manipulating registers in the first place).

Comment: `is it a best practice?` Research macro pitfalls. `Is it not going to slow down the code somehow? I need it to go as fast as possible` Research how compiler optimizations work and strongly remember about the first [rule of optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub) @edit changed link . Prefer writing clean and readable code.